# From select to update Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this(working) select statment:

```
select * from memberships where MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'ZZZ' and inactive_date is null
 and name_id in (select name_id from name where history_yn = 'N')
```

but now i want to change it so it will be an update statement, :

```
update name
set history_yn = 'Y'  
IN (select * from memberships where MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'ZZZ' and inactive_date is null)
```

but I receive ora-00933 error. Could you please advise with this?

Comment: What is the relation between `memberships` and `name`. Or, what is the structure of the tables and the relationship between them altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update name set history_yn = 'Y' 
where name_id IN (select name_id 
                  from memberships 
                  where MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'ZZZ' and inactive_date is null)
and history_yn = 'N'
```

Comment: Hi when i use my select I receive 50 results. But when I use the update I delete more than 200 rows...Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you should add `and history_yn = 'N'` at the end. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Adi: You can accept by clicking the check symbol under the vote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a WHERE clause before the IN. The query can be rewritten as

```
update name set history_yn = 'Y'
WHERE name_id
IN (select name_id from memberships where MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'ZZZ' and inactive_date is null)
```

A more efficient approach might be to use EXISTS instead of IN clause as follows

```
update name n set history_yn = 'Y'
WHERE EXISTS
(select name_id from memberships where MEMBERSHIP_TYPE = 'ZZZ' 
   and inactive_date is null
   and name_id = n.name_id)
```

Comment: Hi when i use my select I receive 50 results. But when I use the update I delete more than 200 rows...Do you have any idea why?